# how find minimum value of this function ? $f=\prod_{i=1}^{20}b_i(x)$

Tags: calculus, analysis

let $0\lt a_1\lt a_2\lt....\lt a_{20}$ ($a_i\in\mathbb R$)and for all i $\in\{1,2,...,20\}$ define $$b_i:(0,\infty)\to \mathbb R$$$$b_i(x)=\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{a_i}{x} ;x\le a_i \\ 
 \\ 
\frac{x}{a_i};x\gt a_i
\end{array}
\right.$$ 
how find minimum value of  $f$ ?  such that $f(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{20}b_i(x)$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean where the minimum value occurs? In order to find the actual minimum value it appears you would need to know the numbers behind $a_i$

Comment: @DanZimmnow i don't find exactly  minimum value of it ?  i try to find the interval that minimum value occurs there(i think this interval is respect to $a_i$ )

Comment: Until now I found the minimum at 10.6 using computer where $a_i,x\in(0,1)$. I believe that the result must be $1$, but probably I am wrong.

Answer (score 2):

I use the fact that the function f is continuous.

For $x<a_{10}$, $f(x)$ has the form of $K/x^n$, so the function is decreasing. The minimum cannot be there

For $x>a_{11}$, $f(x)$ has the form of $K*x^n$, so the function is increasing. The minimum cannot be there

For $a_{11} >x>a_{10} $, $f(x) = \frac{a_{20}*...*a_{11}}{a_{10}*...*a_1}$ is constant. Here is the minimum

Comment: @DanZimm, thanks for the edit, but I finally found how to do by myself ;)

Comment: if $a_i$'s are very close to eachother then can we say that the minimum is $1$?

Comment: No. We can say that the minimum is close to 1 if the $a_i$ are very close, but it will never be equal to 1. Why this question?

Comment: Consider this limit: $$\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { a_{ 20 }*...*a_{ 11 } }{ a_{ 10 }*...*a_{ 1 } }  } =\lim _{ h\rightarrow 0 }{ \frac { \left( a_{ 1 }+19h \right) *...*\left( a_{ 1 }+10h \right)  }{ \left( a_{ 1 }+9h \right) *...*a_{ 1 } }  } $$

Comment: The limit is one, but it is the limit of a sequence of minimums, not a minimum. But once again, what's the point??